# NAS suitable for this situation?

Tags: linux, nas, postgresql

I work from home and am considering getting a NAS. Would using a NAS be suitable for my situation:

- I alternate working from a desktop and laptop, both of which run Linux
- I use PostgreSQL a lot along with doing python development. The idea would be to store the databases on the NAS along with all my program code.
- I would run a copy of PostgreSQL on both the desktop and laptop which would connect to the NAS for the databases. That way when im working on either machine I will have access to my databases and program code.

Would this set work and would a NAS be the way to go?

Also, lets say I update the structure of a database from my desktop. Then at a later time I startup postgresql on the laptop and connect to the database (stored on the NAS) that was updated from the desktop.

Will that cause issues or will postgresql automatically pick up the changes. In other words, when updating the structure of the database from the desktop, is any critical information stored locally on the desktop that pertains to the database,...or is it all in the db itself which will be on the NAS?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve what you want with a NAS no doubt but for a similar outlay I think you could have a much better solution, at least in my opinion.

**Micro Server**

These are cheap to run and provide the functionality of a NAS and much more. A proper server can provide much more flexibility and can be constantly developed to meet your needs exactly.

A server running Ubuntu Server can very easily provide file sharing functionality, it comes out of the box with this functionality.

A server can easily accommodate any SQL software, NAS's can have compatibility issues due to the restrictive nature of the operating system on them.

A server can be configured to run as a web server in minutes, look up Linux Apache MySQL PHP (LAMP), this can obviously be any SQL software you prefer.

The power consumption is slightly higher but is not huge by any means.

A server can easily be expanded to include more HDD's as your storage capacity needs grow.

I have had several NAS units and always found the speed to be a great downfall apart from with the very high end units.

**Further Information**

Refurbished servers can often be picked up very cheap but Micro Servers aren't expensive anyway. I would look into HP ProLiant Micro Servers.

Setting up a fully functional server to carry out your development on will allow you to work on your code, databases and anything else from anywhere with ease as long as you are connected to the Internet.

**SQL Servers**

As to how SQL Servers work, they are a centralised server in which all modifications take place immediately and can be seen from any device.